# How to alter Primary Key to have distinct Auto_Increment based on column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table, called q_locations.

```
 CREATE TABLE `q_locations` (
     `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
     `name` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
     `standalone` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
     UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
     KEY `standalone` (`standalone`)
)
```

I want 'id' to increment from 0, when standalone=0, and to increment from 1000, when standalone=1, is it possible to do that and how?

Comment: @Sadikhasan: What can the user in this case try if he does not know what? Come on, don't just post that comment on every post you can't find a query

Comment: And what will happen if you have more than 999 rows with standalone = 0 ?

Comment: It wont happen, trust me, i have tried searchning for answer elsewhere, but no chances..

Comment: @juergend I mean have you google for solving problem.

Comment: @Sadikhasan: Does such a comment improve anything or add anything useful to it? See [should-stack-overflow-be-awarding-as-for-effort](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/210840/)

Comment: @juergend Thanks for your valuable feedback

Comment: What's your plan if standalone changes value?

Comment: Standalone can't change it's value, because of logic of my application.

Comment: Can anyone help? Trigger isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two way auto increment is not possible but you can achieve this scenario manually by using following logic

**For first entry:**

- Before inserting values into table
- Check the value of standalone
- If it is 0 then insert 0 Else 1000

**For next entries:**

- Before inserting values into table
- Check the value of standalone
- If it is 0 then Get max value of id column by using where condition standalone = 0
- Else if it is 1 then Get max value of id column by using where condition standalone = 1
- Then increment id by 1 and insert it into table

Comment: Can u give me pointers how to do it? I tried trigger in post above you, but it doesn't work at all

Comment: Is it better to implement it on server side?

Comment: I guess it is better to implement increment logic based on standalone value in server side because it is easy readable and maintainable. When we get increment value then will directly insert it in DB with simple insert query

Comment: Thank you very much, now it all makes sense to me :)

Comment: I wont need to use AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY in my DB, right? :)

Comment: If you use also it doesn't matter because it will auto increment only if we didn't pass a value for id, if we pass mysql will take user defined value. i suggest you use auto_increment primary key because it will maintain uniqueness constrains so that no id will get duplicate value

Answer (score 3):

It is possible, but not automatically.  The traditional method is to use a trigger to set the values.

However, I don't think you should pursue this route.  An auto-incremented primary key should not have meaning associated with it.  It is not an encoding of other information; it is just a number assigned to a row (typically in insert order although there may be gaps).

If you want to enumerate the values for `standalone`, then do so in a query rather than in the primary key column.

EDIT:

The trigger would look something like:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_insert_q_locations
BEFORE INSERT ON q_locations
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SELECT coalesce(max(id) + 1, (case when standalone = 0 then 0 else 1000 end)) into NEW.id 
    FROM q_locations 
    WHERE standalone = NEW.standalone;
END$$
```

Note that this handles `insert`.  If the value of `standalone` is updated on a record, the data will be out-of-whack.

Comment: Thanks for good answer. Can u give me some pointers how to do it?

Comment: Definately good solution for me, but it doesn;t work in phpMyAdmin

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')) INTO NEW.id
    FROM q_locations
    WHERE standalone = NEW.standalone;